# Emptying a directory without globbing

Tags: linux, file-management

`rm target_dir/*` apparently only works thanks to the shell expanding the wildcard, so calling `rm` with the argument `target_dir/*` in another way (in my case it's a QProcess in a Qt app) doesn't achieve the same result.
I worked around it by removing the directory and then making it again, but is there an even simpler solution?

Comment: Doesn't the `qdir` class do what you want? Open a dir, then parse the contents... There is also `opendir` & `fopendir`. Those require additional code. You could always call a shell sub-process to handle the deletion.

Comment: @Bib QDir, of course! I hadn't even thought of not calling another QProcess for this. I was in scripting-without-scripting mode.
And the other idea is starting a shell as a QProcess, presumably passing the whole command+args string as an argument? Neat.